# is there any way to make a rally ruby rest api call for workspaces return all of them instead of just default?

Tags: ruby, rally, workspace

i'd like to make a call to rally rest api via ruby toolkit to get all workspaces for a subscription, like so:

```
query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = "workspace"
query.fetch = "ObjectID,Name"
query.project_scope_up = false
query.project_scope_down = true
query.order = "Name Asc"
query.query_string = ""
errors = query.validate()
findResults = @connection.find query
```

but this call apparently only returns the default workspace.

i have semi-successfully been able to navigate to the list of all workspaces when navigating thru the Subscription object, but i would prefer to follow a standard method of going after entity types as illustrated above.

is anyone aware of a way to get all workspaces via a direct query against the workspace type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS API calls are workspace scoped. You are correct that the code above will always return only the default workspace, and that workspaces can be accessed via Subscription object.  Here is an example:

```
require 'rally_api'

#Setup custom app information
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "My Utility"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

# Connection to Rally
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@domain.com"
config[:password] = "secret"
config[:workspace] = "W1"
config[:project] = "P1"
config[:headers] = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)


query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :subscription
query.fetch = "Name,Workspaces,ObjectID"

results = rally.find(query)

sub = results.first
puts sub["Name"]
workspaces = sub["Workspaces"]

workspaces.each do |w|
    puts "Name: #{w["Name"]}, OID: #{w["ObjectID"]}"
end
```

Whenever a query is intended to look outside of a default workspace, a non-default workspace can be specified. Here is an example of a query on defects outside of the default workspace:

```
query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :defect
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,CreationDate,Owner,UserName"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.29/workspace/7777.js" } #optional
query.query_string = "(Owner.UserName = user@company.com)"
```

Comment: thanks nick, any idea what the prevailing 'fetch' behavior is on the associated workspace objects? is there any way to specify that or will it always just be a 'thin' ref to the workspace requiring 1 (or more) roundtrips to the server for attributes? and if additional roundtrips are required would it be at least one per associated object (in this case per workspace)?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding

```
query.workspace = "null"
```

will remove the workspace scoping that is applied by default to queries. I haven't tried this with the Ruby client, but I think it should work.

Comment: StandardError: Errors making Rally Query: ["Workspace - null - must have a ref"]